# Using Xcode to catch crashes in Swift code

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling

I have a simple question. I am trying to debug my iOS app and would like be able to catch errors that crash my app. I looked into using `do try`, but what is the correct format of I just want to catch any error after calling a function.

Here is my question:

```
do
{
    try  update_all_gps()

}
catch
{
    print("Error:########################### \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Suppose the app crashes while executing some where in the `update_all_gps` application like an index out of range, etc. How to I setup the `do try` to catch any fatal errors?

Comment: FYI - An index out of range is an uncatchable exception, not an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use exception breakpoints. See this blog post:
https://www.natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/

Comment: Good answer, but unfortunately I think he needs to catch erros inside his app (and not when developing in Xcode).